# mm/dd/yyyy regex for Regular Expression Validator in ASP.Net failed to validate

Tags: asp.net, regex

I know such questions are in ton and it feels like a dupe question. As I haven't found the solution closed to me, thats why i am posting this. I have a regex in my regular exp validator

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid date format. Valid dates are 12/31/2009 (mm/dd/yyyy). " ControlToValidate="txtDOB" Display="None" EnableTheming="False" EnableViewState="False" SetFocusOnError="True"  ValidationGroup="grpUser"
ValidationExpression="^(?=\d)(?:(?:31(?!.(?:0?[2469]|11))|(?:30|29)(?!.0?2)|29(?=.0?2.(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))(?:\x20|$))|(?:2[0-8]|1\d|0?[1-9]))([-./])(?:1[012]|0?[1-9])\1(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d\d(?:(?=\x20\d)\x20|$))?(((0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d){0,2}(\x20[AP]M))|([01]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){1,2})?$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Its failing to validate the date in mm/dd/yyyy or m/d/yyyy format. I have taken this from RegexLib where the author said its valid for both formats. Are the ^ and $ creating issues.  Please help.

Comment: Is there some reason why you're not using `<asp:CompareValidator Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Date" ...` ?

Comment: @podiluska : Please post your comment as answer so that I can accept and close it. Thanks for guidance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless you have a good reason to do otherwise, you should use a `CompareValidator`

```
<asp:CompareValidator Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Date" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working

```
^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/]\d{4}$
```

Comment: It's also validating 31-02-2015 and 30-02-2015 along with non-leap year's 29-02-yyyy date

Answer (score 1):

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
     ValidationExpression="^([0-9]|0[1-9]|1[012])\/([0-9]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(19|20)\d\d$"
     ControlToValidate="txtDOB" ErrorMessage="Invalid Format. Use MM/DD/YYYY" runat="server"
     ValidationGroup="Password" CssClass="colorred">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

this works for both **m/d/yyyy** and **mm/dd/yyyy** with valid dates